# direct interpretations of an imaginary number

Tags: complex-numbers

There have been many questions about "applications" of complex numbers. **I don't want to ask for examples of how complex numbers are used, but for a specific way to interpret one complex number in an example**. Let me clarify:

**Natural numbers** have many possible interpretations (take nr 5:

- The amount of some collection of objects (there are 5 stones on the table)
- The index of something that identifies it and distinguishes it from other similar objects (go to house nr. 5, instead of house nr. 3)
- distance from some point (the mountain is 5 miles away from our town)
- etc.

**Negative numbers** have been unintuitive to mathematicians in the past, but they also have interpretations (take nr -100):

- The amount of money you owe someone (I have minus 100 dollars. I owe someone 100 dollars)
- The height compared to sea level, if you are under water (we are at negative 100m height. We are 100m below sea level)
- etc

**Rational numbers** also have clear interpretations:

- the part of a larger object (I have 1/3 of a pie)
- the length of an object measured in larger units than that length (this book is 1/3 of an inch thick)
- etc

---

I'll skip irrationals, but can anyone give an interpretion of the **imaginary number** $\sqrt{-x}$?

That is, can you form a sentence that makes sense, which points to the square root of a negative number?

**NOTE:** The examples don't have to be elementary-school-like, as the ones I gave above, but *I am explicitly **not** just looking for a way to use complex number **operations***, because I already know many examples (scaled rotations). I am looking for a way to interpret an actual imaginary number. i.e. a sentence such as: "there is $\sqrt{-5} kJ$ of energy in this room" or something, except that it should make sense.

Comment: Vectors on a plane

Comment: One viewpoint is that a complex number tells you both a magnitude and a phase.  A Fourier coefficient tells you both how much of a pure frequency is present, and what the phase shift is for that frequency.

Comment: msm you cannot possibly have read my question and given that response? Yuriy, that is not an interpretation in the way I explained it. @littleO, this is getting there. But still, it seems to me that the imaginary part of a fourier coefficient is not directly related to the square root of a negative number, the way that "debt" is related to the negative of a natural number. It seems to me that using imaginary numbers for that is mathematically convenient but it doesn't have a clear interpretation that relates it to what the imaginery number is (namely, the sqrt of a negative number).

Comment: If you want a complex number $z$ to have physical significance, perhaps it is better to think of $z$ as $r e^{i\theta}$ rather than as $x + iy$. I think $r$ and $ \theta$ may have more direct physical meaning. In MRI, where Fourier coefficients are measured directly, I think Fourier coefficients are viewed as telling us both a magnitude and a phase. Someone else may be able to explain this in more detail.

Comment: @littleO I appreciate the suggestion to interpret $z$ as $re^{i\theta}$, but that would be counterproductive, because I'm precisely interested in an interpretation of $\sqrt{-n}$. That is, I'm more interested in an interpretation of $i$ than of $z$.

Comment: Maybe have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_impedance (it is something quite meaningful and measurable)

Answer (score 1):

One possible direct interpretation of a complex number is certain linear transformation of a plane.

A real number $x$ can be considered as "scaling" transformation that converts each vector $\mathbf{v}$ to $x \mathbf{v}$. The number $x=-1$ then changes the direction of vectors. What is the "square root" of such transformation? Obviously, it's a rotation of plane by $\pm 90$ degrees.

So a complex number $r e^{i\varphi}$ may be interpreted as **a transformation of the plane** that to a vector $\mathbf{v}$ assigns $R_\varphi (r\mathbf{v})$ where $R_{\varphi}$ is the rotation by $\varphi$. Composition of such linear transformation corresponds to the multiplication of complex numbers. Note that $\pm i$ corresponds to a rotation by $\pm 90$ degrees and $i^2=-1$ means that if you rotate twice, you end up with a transformation that reverses the direction of vectors.

Comment: That would not qualify as a "direct interpretation" the way I am referring to it. I understand that we can see a complex number as a linear transformation, e.g. as the matrix $$
        \left(\begin{matrix}
        a & -b \\
        b & a \\
        \end{matrix}\right)
$$, but this does not "look into" the imaginary number $\sqrt{-n}$. That is, it is not an interpretation of the imaginary number itself, its just an interpretation of an **operation** on a complex number.

Comment: @Programmer2134 No, what I mean is that you may **define** a complex number as a transformation of the plane, not an element of the plane. The multiplication is then defined obviously (although the addition becomes then somehow artificial).  Then the square root of $-1$ is interpreted really as the "complex number" $x$ such that $x\times x=-1$. Whether or not it is "direct" enough, I'm not sure :)

Comment: Because firstly, the rotation is an operation on the complex number, not a complex number itself. Secondly, because it does not relate specifically to the square root of a negative number, which is the definition of imaginary numbers.

Comment: Please don't seek too much in how "direct" is defined. What I am looking for is simply an interpretation of an imaginary number, such as "there is $\sqrt{-5}$ energy in this room", or "this system has $\sqrt{-5}$ hoolahoompah" (whatever hoolahoompah means). I am looking for a way that the sqrt of a negative number can be interpreted. Such examples would be very different from most applications that I've heard of, which simply have an interpretation that is akin to a matrix transformation, and has nothing to do with the fact that $i=\sqrt{-1}$

Comment: if you define complex numbers as transformations, this completely neglects the thing I'm interested in, namely an interpretation of $\sqrt{-n}$

Comment: Yes, admittedly, I changed the interpretation of $-n$ first. But not much.

Comment: By the way, I'm open to the possibility that such interpretations simply don't exist, in which case I would have to disagree with the now popular statement that "imaginary" is bad terminology. But nevertheless, I'd like to look for one.

Comment: For an example of that kind (there is "\sqrt{-5} energy in this room"...) I think that measuring impedance in electric circuits can meaningfully output such results. But it's a long time since I studied some physics, so someone else may explain this better.

Comment: @Programmer2134, those linear transformations are not operations on complex numbers per se, they are operations on the plane. Now why for example a rotation by 90 degrees should be any less real a thing than $-5$, I do not understand.

Comment: @CarstenS I think that he wants a square root of $-5$ where $-5$ is interpreted as "$5$ meters below see level", not as a transformation of vectors..

Comment: @PeterFranek, sure, but he is still wrong ;) Say for me $5$ means $5$ as in “5 apples”. Then $-5$ does not make any sense. To allow for $5$ meters below sea level, we first have to interpret $5$ as “5 meters above sea level“. This is just as much a reinterpretation as it is when I say that I consider $-5$ to be the transformation of the plane that reflects at the origin and scales by $5$ and then consider its square root to be the transformation that results in that transformation when applied twice. (I am not arguing with you, of course.)

Comment: That still wouldn't be an interpretation of $\sqrt{-5}$. It would be an interpretation of the result of "applying" $\sqrt{-5}$ **twice**. In a similar way, an interpretation of "-5" would not be: "the amount that has to be added to 20 in order to get 15". The problem with this is that you are not actually interpreting a negative number. You're only interpreting the result that that negative number has on positive numbers. Consequently, this type of negative number (basically subtraction) was not counterintuitive before 1500.

Comment: the intuitive jump that people made was that negative numbers could **exist in their own right** (that is, not just as an operator that results in a postivie number), and they can be interpreted as e.g. debt, i.e. negative cash. Similarly, you have still not given an interpretation of $\sqrt{-5}$ **in its own right**, but only as an operator that results in a real number.

Answer (score 0):

> I'll skip irrationals, but can anyone give an interpretation of the imaginary number $\sqrt{-x}$? or of the complex number $a + \sqrt{-x}$?
>
> That is, can you form a sentence that makes sense, which points to the square root of a negative number?
>
> I am explicitly not just looking for a way to complex number operations

Sense is a very subjective thing. A familiar thing makes more sense than an unfamiliar one. So, perhaps, if my choice of examples does not strike you as sensible, I hope, you would have a bit of patience with my point of view.

Continuing with your analogy, let us first have a one for real numbers.

**Real Numbers** - Imagine an infinite line, with some point predefined as origin and some unit of measurement. A real number can be used to mark some position on the line.

Now, consider $x \epsilon R$ and $y \epsilon R$. What is a good way to understand a pair of real numbers?

**Pair of real numbers** - Imagine an infinite plane with some point predefined as origin and some unit of measurement. A pair of real numbers $(x, y)$ can be used to mark some position on the plane.

This is how I make sense of complex numbers. Normally, when I do this, most of my students cry foul! "This is not complex numbers, this is coordinate geometry".

So, let me elaborate. Another system which makes use of this representation of *pair of real numbers* is vectors. When I write a vector (2, 3), you would automatically assume an arrow on a plane or a point on a plane. But that is not enough for something to be a vector.
A vector also needs to have some operations defined, namely '+', '$\times$' and '$\cdot$'. Without these operations, we won't be able to call $(x, y)$ to be a vector.

**Vector** - A vector is tuple of real numbers such that the operations '+', '$\times$' and '$\cdot$' follow some specific rules.

Some of these operations are more sensible than others. The '+' and '$\cdot$' operations are good, but the '$\times$' is a very difficult one to intuit.

The point being, after the basic type *pair of real number*, if we want to understand further specializations like vectors and complex numbers, we need to understand the operations which they entail.

With this in mind, let us define a new class -

**Not yet complex number (NYCN)** - A pair of real numbers $(a, b)$ with operations '+' and '$\cdot$' defined as follows -

$(a, b) + (c, d) = (a + c, b + d)$ and

$(a, b) \cdot (c, d) = (ac - bd, ad + bc)$

How do we interpret the '$\cdot$' operation? It has two functions, rotation and scaling. If you take an arrow $(x, y)$ and want to rotate it anti-clockwise by say $\theta$, you could get the new point by performing $(x, y) \cdot (\cos \theta, \sin \theta)$.

This rotation operation is what differentiates us from vectors. The problem with operation is in its pedagogy - it is so different from everything we have done yet (unless you count cross product in vectors).

So, how do we reconcile these operations with our previous versions of '$\cdot$'. What follows is cosmetic surgery -

**Complex Numbers** - $x + iy$ is a complex number for ($x, y \epsilon R$), if $(x, y)$ is a NYCN.

$i$ is a constant which does not 'interact' with a real number much like $\hat{i}$ in vectors. Now, we want complex numbers to have our real number like addition and multiplication rules.
Addition - $a + ib + c + id = (a + c) + i(b + d)$. So the new NYCN is $(x_1 + x_2, y_1 + y_2)$ which is good for us.
Multiplication - $(a + ib) \cdot (c + id) = ac + i^2bd + i(ad + bc)$. This is very close to our requirement of NYCN. The $y$ term is perfect - $(ad + bc)$. But the $x$ term has $i^2$ instead of -1.

So, for complex numbers to have same functionality as NYCN, we need to take $i^2 = -1$.

"But this does not make sense!! Why take $i^2 = -1$?"
Don't. Work with NYCNs. You would be good. The $i^2 = -1$ is a tool which makes things cleaner and equations become more beautiful. If you don't like makeup, don't put it on. The thing is, a bit of makeup does wonders to one's looks.

Comment: I think I completely understand your way of thinking. It is a very reasonable approach. I think underlying this is basically an attitude of: "don't think about what it means, just make sure you can use it". I don't think there is anything wrong with this intrinsically, but if means that your answer to my question is basically "you should not ask that question at all". However I won't do that, because I'm still interested if there is an interpretation of $\sqrt{-5}$.

Comment: Fair enough. I didn't mean, "You should not ask that question at all", it was more of an experience with young kids where they ask something but mean to ask something else. I hope somebody benefits from this. :)